Does GitHub Copilot within VSCode have a requirement on NodeJS version?
I just installed GitHub Copilot in VSCode locally and it worked great.  I then connected to one of my remote workspaces (SSH) and installed the extension.  It seems that the extension isn't initializing correctly or fully though.  The button in the chat window just keeps saying "Use Copilot for Free".  The output window for GitHub Copilot shows a certificate error and my guess is that it is due to the NodeJS version installed on my server (node 16).  I don't see any minimum requirement stated for VSCode on the GitHub Copilot documentation, however the documentation for using it in Vim/Neovim I do see that Node 18+ is required.  can anyone confirm?
The error in the output log is:
2024-12-19 09:24:12.377 [warning] [certificates] Failed to parse certificate # DigiCert Global Root G2
 Error: error:0480006C:PEM routines::no start line
    at new X509Certificate (node:internal/crypto/x509:119:21)
    at /home/myuser/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.253.0/lib/src/network/certificateReaders.ts:79:36
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at Pne.removeExpiredCertificates (/home/myuser/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.253.0/lib/src/network/certificateReaders.ts:77:32)
    at Pne.getAllRootCAs (/home/myuser/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.253.0/lib/src/network/certificateReaders.ts:68:38)
    at Cue.createSecureContext (/home/myuser/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.253.0/lib/src/network/certificates.ts:46:23) {
  opensslErrorStack: [
    'error:0688010A:asn1 encoding routines::nested asn1 error',
    'error:06800066:asn1 encoding routines::bad object header',
    'error:0680009B:asn1 encoding routines::too long'
  ],
  library: 'PEM routines',
  reason: 'no start line',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE',
  vslsStack: [
    CallSite {},
    CallSite {},
    CallSite {},
    CallSite {},
    CallSite {},
    CallSite {}
  ]
}

